# Save CheckBoxlist values to database using asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr);
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into reg (name,num,gender,qual) values
(@name,@num,@gender,@qual)", con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", TextBox1.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@num", TextBox2.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gender",     
 RadioButtonList1.SelectedItem.ToString());
        for (int i = 0; i < CheckBoxList1.Items.Count - 1;i++ )
        {
            if(CheckBoxList1.Items[1].Selected)
            {
                string var = string.Empty;
                var += CheckBoxList1.Items[1].Text.ToString();
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@qual",var);
            }
        }
        try
        {
            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            Response.Write("<script language='javascript'>alert(
               'record has been added');</script>");
        }
        catch (Exception er)
        {
            Response.Write("<script language='javascript'>alert(
          'conncetion error');</script>");
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
        }
```

I am beginner of `asp.net`. I don't know how to save the checkboxlist values to data base. I the above code it saves only the last value. Please help me, thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are iterating through loop but only comparing value 1 all the time I have changed 1 to i. 
And I think you need to collect values and and them all only once.To perfoem that I have moved cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@qual",s); statement out of for loop

Note: I am separating values with ',' I don't know that is your business need or not

```
 string s;
 for (int i = 0; i < CheckBoxList1.Items.Count - 1;i++ )
    {
        if(CheckBoxList1.Items[i].Selected)//changed 1 to i 
            s += CheckBoxList1.Items[i].Text.ToString() + ","; //changed 1 to i
    }

 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@qual",s);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're only executing the command once, outside of the for-loop.

If you move the Execute query into the for loop it should work.

Note that this will fix your code, but it will neither safe or optimal.